# Will passing a value type variable by reference into a static method thread safe?

Tags: .net, thread-safety, interlocked

the code looks like this:

```
public class JobManager
{
    public static void TrackExceptionCount(ref int exceptionCount)
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref exceptionCount);
    }

    //other helper methods
}
```

I will call this method in other place like:

```
private static int _exceptionCount;

JobManager.TrackExceptionCount(ref _exceptionCount);
```

I thought Interlocked.Increment will handle the thread-safe problem, right?

Edit:

I have multiple Job class like this:

```
class JobA
{
    private static int _exceptionCount;

    public void method1()
    {
       Task.Factory.Start(()=>{
         try
         {
             //Some code
         }
         catch(exception ex)
         {
            JobManager.TrackExceptionCount(ref _exceptionCount);
         }
       });
    }

    public void method2()
    {
       Task.Factory.Start(()=>{
         try
         {
             //Some code
         }
         catch(exception ex)
         {
            JobManager.TrackExceptionCount(ref _exceptionCount);
         }
       });
    }
}

class JobB
{
    private static int _exceptionCount;

    public void method1()
    {
       Task.Factory.Start(()=>{
         try
         {
             //Some code
         }
         catch(exception ex)
         {
            JobManager.TrackExceptionCount(ref _exceptionCount);
         }
       });
    }

    public void method2()
    {
       Task.Factory.Start(()=>{
         try
         {
             //Some code
         }
         catch(exception ex)
         {
            JobManager.TrackExceptionCount(ref _exceptionCount);
         }
       });
    }
}
```

I believe that direct call Interlocked.Increment in the catch block probably a better way.

But still want to know if the JobManager.TrackExceptionCount(ref _exceptionCount) will be working probably, or not

Thanks.

Comment: No, the *static* keyword ruins your day.  Interlocked might work, but of course your code snippet is entirely inadequate to see where else it gets used.

Comment: Do you have any evidence that doing this is not thread-safe? Have you had any errors? Or are you just trying to confirm or deny your suspicions?

Comment: Hi Enigmativity, I just met a case similar like this, so want to confirm or deny this suspicions.

Comment: Hi @JeffChen - you need to use the @ notation to ensure a notification gets sent. It was just luck that I checked this question again.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your call to `Interlocked.Increment` is the only usage of the storage location `_exceptionCount` this is safe. You can pass `ref` parameters around safely. They work a little like a managed pointer to to variable (internally, they are).

Comment: Thanks usr, _exceptionCount is only used to pass into interlock